# Is there a host system unique ID in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

Is there any chance to get an unique host system ID within my VM that is hosted in VirtualBox?

Asked different: is there an unique ID of the host system that I can read from the virtual machine. In case I import the same VM into another host system, can the VM detect that it runs in another host system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With KVM/libvirt you can run `dmidecode -t system` on the host VM, it exports the UUID generated in libvirt from the XML description. It should be unique to each VM.

Comment: The question was tagged [tag:virtualbox]. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: From my googling there appears to be good indication that the same values can also exported in virtualbox.

Comment: I get `UUID: EAF44EA1-F755-4E9C-B506-400...`, seems to be good

Comment: @MIfe oooOOOOoo, spifftastic.

Comment: @PeterMmm But isn't this only on the host system and not from within the guest?

Comment: @Wesly I'm running Debian guest on Win7 host and runnig the mentioned command on Debian. I get the posted UUID and a different on a newly imported (cloned) VM.

Answer (score 2):

Each `.vdi` file has a UUID that can be seen by using the `vboxmanage` command. For example `vboxmanage showhdinfo \path\to\file.vdi`

From within the guest [you'll need to read MIfe's answer!](https://serverfault.com/a/560959/9770) =) <strike>first user vboxmanage from the host to set a GuestProperty starting like this: `vboxmanage guestproperty set` and name it UUID. Then from within the guest you'll retrieve it with vboxcontrol, something like this: `vboxcontrol guestproperty get /VirtualBox/GuestProperty/whateverYouNamedTheProperty`</strike>

Comment: Running `vboxmanage` on host system. But I'm interested in getting an ID from within the VM ...